# How do I plot a vertical line with different colors, based on values in a database?

Tags: python-3.x, class, plot

I am trying to plot a vertical line which represents depth. On different depths different types of soil are present and I would like to indicate these with different colors.

I have received data which is stored in a class. Based on a friction number I want to color the vertical line in three different colors. However, I don't know how I can achieve this.

The data is stored in ds1 (I have many different files (ds2, ds3, .. ds29) so making this work is convenient for me). ds1.depth calls the depth array, ds1.frictionnumber the friction number etc.

Due to the large amount of data and soil changes I don't know how to do this. It would be nice if something like below would work but I cannot get my head around it.

*UPDATE: I found some code here -> http://abhay.harpale.net/blog/python/how-to-plot-multicolored-lines-in-matplotlib/*

*I adjusted my code and I get quite reasonable results, however something still goes wrong. In my data I've got 4 NaN values at the end (friction did not get measured). In the image below this should be from the horizontal line down, however that's not the case. How can I solve this, or what is going wrong?*

*UPDATE 2: The height of the line apparantly also scales with linewidth. Now I only need to find another way of plotting a wider line. Any suggestions are welcome.*

```
def find_contiguous_colors(colors):
    # finds the continuous segments of colors and returns those segments
    segs = []
    curr_seg = []
    prev_color = ''
    for c in colors:
        if c == prev_color or prev_color == '':
            curr_seg.append(c)
        else:
            segs.append(curr_seg)
            curr_seg = []
            curr_seg.append(c)
        prev_color = c
    segs.append(curr_seg) # the final one
    return segs

def plot_multicolored_lines(x,y,colors):
    segments = find_contiguous_colors(colors)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    start= 0
    for seg in segments:
        end = start + len(seg)
        l, = plt.gca().plot(x[start:end],y[start:end],lw=50,c=seg[0]) 
        start = end
    plt.axhline(-5.8988)
    plt.axis('equal')

x = np.full(len(ds1.depth), 1)
y = ds1.depth 
# color segments
colors = ['red']*len(ds1.depth)
for i in range(len(ds1.depth)):
    if 0 < ds1.wrijvingsgetal[i] <= 1:
        colors[i] = 'blue'
    elif 1 < ds1.wrijvingsgetal[i] <= 2:
        colors[i] = 'green'
    elif ds1.wrijvingsgetal[i] > 2: 
        colors[i] = 'yellow'
    else:
        colors[i] = 'magenta'
```

[Vertical soil profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLnBf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not efficient at all but I get the results I want. If someone knows how I could fix this by using stacked bargraph that is appreciated (for some reason I can't get it to work). My fix is presented below:

```
ds1 = read_gef(filepath)

def find_contiguous_colors(colors):
    # finds the continuous segments of colors and returns those segments
    segs = []
    curr_seg = []
    prev_color = ''
    for c in colors:
        if c == prev_color or prev_color == '':
            curr_seg.append(c)
        else:
            segs.append(curr_seg)
            curr_seg = []
            curr_seg.append(c)
        prev_color = c
    segs.append(curr_seg) 
    return segs

def plot_multicolored_lines(x, y, colors):
    segments = find_contiguous_colors(colors)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    start= 0
    for seg in segments:
        end = start + len(seg)
        l, = plt.gca().plot(x[start:end], y[start:end], lw=2, c=seg[0]) 
        start = end
    #plt.axhline(-5.8988, -1, 1)

x = np.full((len(ds1.depth), 2), 0)
y = np.array(ds1.depth) 

# color segments
colors = ['red']*len(ds1.depth)
handle = [0] * 3
for i in range(len(ds1.depth)):
    if 0 < ds1.wrijvingsgetal[i] <= 2:
        colors[i] = 'yellow'
        sandplt = plt.axhline(y[i], color=colors[i])
#    elif 1 < ds1.wrijvingsgetal[i] <= 2:
#        colors[i] = 'green'
#        peatplt = plt.axhline(y[i], color=colors[i]) 
    elif ds1.wrijvingsgetal[i] > 2: 
        colors[i] = 'green'
        clayplt = plt.axhline(y[i], color=colors[i])
    else:
        colors[i] = 'magenta'
        nanplt = plt.axhline(y[i], color=colors[i])


ratioxl = 1/5
plt.xlim(0, ratioxl*(ds1.depth[-1]-ds1.depth[0]))
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.ylabel('Depth w.r.t. groundlevel [m]')
plt.title('Vertical soil profile ' + str(Path(filepath).stem))
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom=False,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top=False,         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom=False) # labels along the bottom edge are off
plt.legend(handles = (sandplt, clayplt, nanplt), labels=['Sand', 'Clay', 'Nan'], loc=[1.01, 0.78])
plt.savefig(os.path.join(wd, '..', '03data', '20190711-Wiertsema', 'VN72650-1_GEF', 'afbeeldingen') + '\VSP_' + str(Path(filepath).stem))
plt.show()
```